# C# application to test microphone

Tags: c#, microphone

Visual Studio 2005 SP2

I have developed a softphone for our client.

However, they want to add a feature that will test the microphone level. Like the windows version does using the wizard.

Just to get me started and point me in the right direction is there any web site tutorials on how to do this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could just lunch the Windows Training Wizard

"%SystemRoot%\System32\Speech\SpeechUX\SpeechUXWiz.exe" MicTraining .